# Does a recv() already waiting for data detect shut down of the socket from the other end?

Tags: c, sockets

I am transferring the contents of a file to a client and on completion of the transfer I shut down the TX socket (`shutdown(hdl, SHUT_WR)`). The client side depends on the detection of orderly shut down of the socket to exit the loop for receiving data.

I notice that the detection happens (recv() returns 0) only sometimes while other times it just blocks. I suspect a race condition between the shutdown() and the final recv() i.e. when the socket is closed before the recv() call is made I can detect the orderly shut down, however if the recv() is already blocking for data and the socket is shutdown() at this point then the client is unable to detect it.

Is my diagnosis right?
Irrespective of the answer to the above question - how do I better handle detection of end of transmission without resorting to OOB means?

P.S. : If it matters - I am using CYGWIN on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: There shouldn't be a race condition, that would be an incredibly serious bug in the network stack. You should always receive the EOF when the sender shuts down the socket.

Comment: It's more likely there's a deadlock in your code. Have you done a packet capture to see if the `FIN` is being sent on the TX socket?

Comment: No, when the socket is closed or shutdown you `recv()` should return immediately, unless the communication between the hosts is severed and the `FIN/RST` package is lost.

Comment: @Barmar - No I haven't done a packet capture yet. And I don't think there is an intermittent deadlock in my code; I will check again nevertheless.

Comment: @rodrigo - A `shutdown(hdl, SHUT_WR)` is good enough right? Or does it require `shutdown(hdl, SHUT_RDWR)` or a `close()`?

Comment: `SHUT_WR` should be enough.

Comment: @work.bin: A `SHUT_WR` on the sender socket will shutdown the reader half of the receiver socket, that is what you want. If you close a socket without  `shutdown()`ing it... well, you may get an error, that is `recv()` returning  `-1` (`errno=ECONNRESET`) instead of `0`. I think that the details vary between Windows and Linux, and maybe can be changed with socket options,

Comment: Are you implementing the FTP protocol?  If not, then why are you relying on `shutdown()` to signal EOF? Why not send the actual file size so the reader knows exactly how much data to expect? Then it can stop reading when X bytes have been read, and *any* failure from `recv()`, (even 0) would be an incomplete transfer.